# Android - How to download Image and save it in desired location?

Tags: java, android, download

I am trying to save image i.e. user avatar or profile picture in a Folder named `myApp`. I tried some methods but none work.

**Here is the Code**

```
public void downloadImage(String src) {
    try {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        createDirectoryAndSaveFile(myBitmap, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

    File direct = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File dir = new File(direct.getAbsoluteFile() + "/myApp/" );
    dir.mkdir();
    File file = new File(dir, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Here is the Error**

```
2020-08-15 15:12:06.501 21637-21637/com.mycompany.newchatapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mycompany.newchatapp, PID: 21637
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
    at com.mycompany.newchatapp.Activities.ViewMedia.getBitmapFromURL(ViewMedia.java:60)
    at com.mycompany.newchatapp.Activities.ViewMedia.onOptionsItemSelected(ViewMedia.java:49)
```

So, how can I download images and save it in desired Location?

Comment: Just try to call downloadImage method in a thread, instead of calling it on the main (ui) thread

Comment: @JeffWong I am calling it on onOptionsItemSelected. When a button is clicked from the menu. So, what changes should I make.

Comment: This is the most easy way ```AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                downloadImage();
            }
        });```

Comment: @JeffWong The Error has been removed but I can't find the directory nor the image

Comment: You should create the directory before you try to download a file in it. And if you wanna use mkdirs() then only use it if the directory does not exist yet. And if you use mkdirs() then check the return value. And if the directory is not created then dont download that file. Start adapting your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here, The Writing and Networking operation is getting executed on the Main Thread.So it throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

A possible fix for this problem is to move `downloadImage()` off the mainThread.
This can be done by using AsyncTasks or java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities.

Here's how you can do this with AsyncTasks:

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private Exception exception;
    protected void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0]
            .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            createDirectoryAndSaveFile(myBitmap, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Another cleaner Solution to this problem is to use Glide:

Using Glide:

```
Glide.with(context)
 .asBitmap()
 .load(url)
 .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
     @Override
     public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource,Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
        createDirectoryAndSaveFile(resource, Filename);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using Glide to display the image. And Can you elaborate your Glide code for my understanding?

Comment: You can learn about `onResourceReady()`  [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/440/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestListener.html). Glide  will basically do the network stuff for you and when the resource(image) is ready , it will save it by calling your `CreateDirectoryAndSaveFile()`